# Pushing changes to Git repository results in 'Updates were rejected' error, how to fix it?

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I have an online repository on which I am the only person that can push commits, and there are no more branches than the main one. I have been working on it these days, and pushed commits without an issue, including folders and files etc.

Except today, when I try to push changes to update the repository with the latest files and folders I have, it gives me this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
To https://github.com/repo.git
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
!   refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main [rejected] (non-fast-forward)
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
Done
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I am using Pycharm Community Edition 13.2, and always update by selecting the Commit section in the left bar menu and then writing a comment and pushing the commit like in here: [image]

I also never touched the online repository to make any changes, always kept local files which were then pushed. I already tried to fetch and to update the project but it didn't fix, so before I break my repository I want to ask for help

EDIT: I did make some changes to the online repository. I had added a LICENSE.md file which shows up in my remote history changes. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you are the only one who push on that repository, but Github tells you that your head is older (behind) the remote one.

Before of all, I suggest you to inspect the remote history to check if somebody (?) pushed something else.

If you will discover some remote changes you should do a git pull with a rebase by `git pull -r`.

Comment: If you are new to git I would suggest not rebasing, since it has more chance of leading to conflicts. Just use `git pull`

Comment: I am not new. I case of conflicts it is enough to issue a `git merge --abort` and proceed with `git pull` which will do an automatic merge.

Comment: I know you are not new, but I think OP is

Comment: Yeah, you were right @AntonioPetricca. The issue seems to be that I added a LICENSE.md from the GitHub instead of locally. I am editing the question to show the remote history.

Comment: Just answering the comment to say this worked and fixed the conflict, grazie mille @AntonioPetricca ;)

Comment: Di nulla SPOOL :)